# error within this context tags may tag wrong location

Tags: c++, c++11

Win7 64-bits

cygwin g++ 4.8.3 (-std=gnu+11)

I've got a little code with a little problem.

```
class InputClass {
private:
   vector<string>& str;
   istream in;                  // no code, no error
public:
   InputClass(vector<string> str) : str(str) { }
}; // class InputClass
```

Why does "istream in;" produce an error and why is "str(str)" tagged as being wrong. When "istream in;" is removed, no error.

Complete error message et al:

```
g++ -Wall  -Wunused-variable -std=gnu++11   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/iostream:40:0,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/istream: In constructor 'InputClass::InputClass(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/istream:606:7: error: 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected
       basic_istream()
       ^
main.cpp:44:44: error: within this context
    InputClass(vector<string> str) : str(str) { }
                                            ^
```

Comment: Might be a good question, please make a complete test case - provide a main()

Comment: The question is, why does "str(str)" have an error when "istream in" is present and does not have an error when it is not? I am not much concerned with the "istream in" because (I figure) that that's my problem and that I caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that `istream` is not default constructible, but you are trying to default construct it. There exists a `protected` default constructor - probably for some other classes - but you're not allowed to use it. The only one you're allowed to use is:

```
explicit istream(streambuf* );
```

But there's another problem with this constructor: you are constructing your `str` as a reference to the temporary `str` that `InputClass` accepts. So once the constructor completes, you're left with a dangling reference. You need to accept the source `vector` by reference rather than by value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `istream` using a buffer. In your code the default constructor will be called.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out (I'm using ifstream), but thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The essential error message is

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/istream:606:7: error: 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected
   basic_istream()
```

You cannot instantiate a [`istream in;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) member using the default constructor. [There's no default constructor available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream) for `std::istream`.

---

**You can have** for instance a `istream& in;` reference member, along with an appropriate constructor:

```
class InputClass {
private:
    vector<string>& str;
    istream& in;
        // ^
public:
    InputClass(vector<string> str) : str(str), in(std::cin) { }
                                               // ^^^^^^^^
}; // class InputClass
```

or use one of the available constructor functions as mentioned

```
class InputClass {
private:
    vector<string>& str;
    istream in;
public:
    InputClass(vector<string> str, std::streambuf* sb) 
                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    : str(str), in(sb) {}
           ^ // ^^^^^^
}; // class InputClass
```